# App Engine going crazy after some hours of a new deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I was a bit unsure how to title this question, as I'm quite unsure where the problems is. Recently we upgraded to Go 1.11 as 1.9 is deprecated as of oct 1, unfortunately it wasn't a smooth transition.

I did all changes needed, got it running just fine and it worked well for around 10 hours. Then all the suddenly requests start taking 10 minutes (but they shouldn't take more than 1min ever?) and this causes new instances to be created but no requests go through successfully. (As a side-note, I didn't have a max instances value set so at one point 500 were created. Now it's capped)

Yesterday I fixed a couple null pointer errors that got reported (5 reports in total), re deployed and again, same thing. Here's the log from when it happened:

[image]

Everything was working fine, until it wasn't. And zero errors have been reported.

The function called is pretty simple, a couple datastore reads and and every now and then a write. No for loops that could turn into infinite for loops and so forth.

I'm a bit lost where to go next, I migrated traffic back to the 1.9 version for now.

Comment: No this happened yesterday (Sept 27) and today again. As you can see in the log there

Comment: An error is being reported. The last log line shows a `500` on the 10th (!) `POST` to `/clan/poll/quests`. The App Engine default timeout is 60 seconds after which time, the service will terminate the request. 10 attempts on this request comes out to ~600 seconds (602.1 seconds is shown). So, if you're not already, you should determine whether it's always this endpoint that's failing and then dig into `/clan/poll/guests`.

Comment: You may also wish to consider: Stackdriver Error Reporting (https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/go) to dig into any errors from your code and Stackdriver Profiler (https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-go)

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin I'll try the stack driver error reporting tool. Also, once one request fails all other fail as well, and critical errors were reported on the AppEngine dashboard(I guess those would be panic() errors?). I got GoLand now instead of just a syntax hightlight editor and it did find some warnings, so next step will be to go through the warnings and fix those and add the improved error reporting.

Comment: Error Reporting will enable to capture errors from the running service. The endpoint looks to be panicking. Error Reporting should help you identify the underlying problem.

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was I replaced every datastore.Put() with a dsClient = datastore.NewClient(...) dsClient.put(), and that created a ton of open connections, when I added a defer close it worked, but still consumed a ton of memory, but switching it to one shared datastore client fixed all issues.